# Polymorphism C++: field of base pointer not using value given by derived class constructor

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm running into an issue with this code (it's a simplified version from a personal project):

```
#include <iostream>

class Piece
{
public:
    Piece() : art('=') {};

    char art;
};

class Pawn : public Piece
{
public:
    Pawn() : art('p') {};

    char art;
};

int main()
{
    Piece* piece = new Pawn; // piece->art should be 'p'
    std::cout << piece->art; // =
    
    return 0;   
}
```

In my project I'm trying to have an array of pieces of different types, which I was planning to do using `Piece*` objects. However, when I call the constructor for `Pawn` (or any other derived object) it seems like the base constructor is called instead.

Furthermore,

```
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece() : art('=') {};

    char art;
};

class Pawn : public Piece
{
public:
    Pawn() : art('p') {};
};
```

is apparently illegal, as `Pawn` does not have an `art` field, although it should inherit that from the base class!

Could someone enlighten me? How can I make it such that the constructor of the derived class is called instead? How can I get an array (vector) of `Piece` objects, which can be either `Pawn`, or other derived objects?

Comment: Why does both `Piece` and `Pawn` have their own `art` variable?

Comment: I don't want `Piece` to have an `art` field, however the compiler complains that it did not exist when I initially tried diagnosing this problem. When calling the base constructor like @cigien instructed, the compiler allows removing the pointless field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call the base class constructor like this:

```
class Pawn : public Piece
{
public:
    Pawn() : Piece('p') {}
         //  ^^^^^ not 'art'
};
```

See the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) for member initializer lists, which explains how this works.

---

If you have a `std::vector<Piece*>` it can store pointers to objects to derived types, such as `Pawn*`.

Comment: Thank you. The compiler also now allows removing `art` field in the `Pawn` (derived) class.

Comment: Well, that was a bug in the first place. If you inherit from `Piece` there is already a `art` member in `Pawn`.

Comment: @finicu Having `art` in both classes is allowed but probably a mistake. Your `Pawn` type would have two different members with the name `art` (`Pawn::art` and `Piece::art`) which are unrelated to each other and can have different values. This is why your first attempt was allowed to compile and why it looked like `art` didn't have the value you expected. You were looking at the value of the wrong `art` member.